# Lazy loading doesn't work for OneToMany relationship on Spring Boot

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I've been working with spring boot data jpa + spring + mysql + thymeleaf and have encountered a problem.
Is a `@OneToMany (fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` relationship for a list, the list loads hibernate like `@OneToMany (fetch = FetchType.EAGER)` outside. But if I use the annotation `@ManyToOne` this does work perfectly.

Any idea why it happens this behavior?
By the way, I want to keep the spring.jpa.open-in-view = true property. I debug an application Author - Book (`One to Many`) developed in `IntelliJ IDEA`.

Here's the Book class.

```
@Entity
public class Book implements Serializable {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private Integer id;

   @NotNull
   private String name;

   @NotNull
   @JoinColumn(name = "author_id")
   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   private Author author;

  /* getters and setters */
}
```

Here the class Author

```
@Entity
public class Author implements Serializable {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private Integer id;

   @NotNull
   private String name;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "author", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   private List<Book> bookList;

   /* getters and setteres */
}
```

The controller for debug.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    private AuthorRepository authorRepository;

    @Autowired
    private BookRepository bookRepository;

    @GetMapping
    private ModelAndView index() {
        List<Author> authorList = authorRepository.findAll();
        return new ModelAndView("home"); // first breakpoint
    }

    @GetMapping("/books")
    private ModelAndView viewBooks() {
        List<Book> bookList = bookRepository.findAll();
        return new ModelAndView("books"); // second breakpoint
    }

}
```

Here's the result.

First breakpoint result
[image: First breakpoint result]

Second breakpoint result
[image: Second breakpoint result]

Comment: lazy fetch type will execute the fetching once you'll try to access the object. where is your code that uses to load/get the entities? can you post it?

Comment: I'm only debugging with Intellij IDEA debug. The result of first breakpoint shouldn't load the book list. In this case the book list size should be 0. The first breakpoint result is here [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/oArYW.png).

Comment: I'll appreciate if you post your code, tnx.

Comment: Yeah sorry. That's my code on GitHub https://github.com/DarwinGalindo/lazy-my-app-problem

Comment: I'm not sure. everything seems to be defined correctly, and after a research, I have done Spring data does use lazy loading plus you defined it on your associations. I believe that when you use the debugging views in order to tell what inside, then you actually do the fetching. try to figure if that's the case.

Comment: You're right. I compared debugging in IntelliJ IDEA and STS. On STS the list of books for authorList object is not loaded, ie @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY) works perfectly. I think the problem is in the IDE IntelliJ IDEA. Anyway thank you very much.

Comment: I'll appreciate if you mark my answer as completed with green V, and give it a grade up. tnx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything seems to be defined correctly, and after a research, I have done Spring data does use lazy loading plus you defined it on your associations.

I believe that when you use the debugging views in order to tell what inside, then you actually do the fetching.

Comment: I have to agree. If I run my program in standard mode, the related entity with lazy loading is never fetched from the DB. If I run it in debug mode, I can see the SQL query retrieving the related entity.